# How to recover vhd file?

Tags: data-recovery, hyper-v, vhd, hyper-v-manager, vhdx

Tried to convert a `vhd` file to a `vhdx` file using the `Hyper-V Manager`. The manager gave an error saying it could find the file (not sure which one).

Used windows explorer to go to the location of the vhd file and it wasn't there.

Checked the storage and noticed there was 600 gb free space where usually it was 400 gb. My `vhd` was 200gb.

Checked my recycle bin (knowing large files don't go there), nothing.

I didn't get a question are you sure you want to delete .... so no I didn't delete the file. In 2 minutes the file was gone, from shutting down the virtual machine to the time I couldn't find the file anymore. SO even if I tried to delete the file, it would have taken longer then 2 minutes to delete the file (there would be a proces window).

So where did the vhd go and how do I get it back?

Comment: "it would have taken longer then 2 minutes to delete the file (there would be a proces window)." - I can delete a 1TB in such a way you won't know it's even happening (without user confirmation) and it will be nearly instantaneous

Comment: "how do I get it back?" - It sounds like the file is permanently lost.

Comment: @Ramhound `Shift+Delete` is one way to delete, but I wasn't using the keyboard at all (so cli commands are out of the question to)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

1. Right-click on the folder in which the VHD was stored.
2. Select Properties...
3. Go to "Previous Versions" tab.
4. See if you can find a copy of the VHD in the old versions of the folder, if any exists.

If that failed, download and install [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) or another file recovery app. See if you can recover your VHD to another drive.

Whether you are able to recover your file or not, in the end, run a full Chkdsk on the drive containing the VHD and then perform a virus scan. A file disappearing just like that is a sign of trouble. And even though as of late, Microsoft has released nothing but buggy software, I don't think Hyper-V Manager deleted your file.

Comment: Already tried Recuva, nothing. Shadow copy isn't configured, so no previous versions. No virusses found. The only thing running or attempted to run was Hyper-V manager trying to convert `vhd` to `vhdx`.